# composer network start with error SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i used cello to install fabric network (2 org , 2 peers per each organization, 1 ca) then we followed the [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html) but we have only one ca instead of ca per org and when we run command

```
 composer network start -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -a tutorial-network/tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna -o endorsementPolicyFile=endorsement-policy.json -A alice -C alice/admin-pub.pem -A bob -C bob/admin-pub.pem
```

we get this error

```
✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: Error: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
Command failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with the orderer. This error is thrown when the ordering service is unavailable. Please check the logs of the orderer